# Subprocess call invalid argument or option not found

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm trying to call ffmpeg command using subprocess.call() on linux, but I'm unable to get the arguments right. Before hand, I used os.system and it worked, but this method is not recommended.

Using arguments with a dash such as "-i" gets me this error

```
Unrecognized option 'i "rtsp://192.168.0.253:554/user=XXX&password=XXX&channel=0&stream=0.sdp?real_stream"'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Using arguments without dash like "i" gets me this error

```
[NULL @ 0x7680a8b0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'i rtsp://192.168.0.253:554/user=admin&password=&channel=0&stream=0.sdp?real_stream'
i rtsp://192.168.0.253:554/user=XXX&password=XXX&channel=0&stream=0.sdp?real_stream: Invalid argument
```

Here's the code

```
class IPCamera(Camera):
"""
    IP Camera implementation
"""
def __init__(self,
             path='\"rtsp://192.168.0.253:554/'
                  'user=XXX&password=XXX&channel=0&stream=0.sdp?real_stream\"'):

    """
        Constructor
    """
    self.path = path

def __ffmpeg(self, nb_frames=1, filename='capture%003.jpg'):
    """
    """

    ffm_input = "-i " + self.path
    ffm_rate = "-r 5"
    ffm_nb_frames = "-vframes " + str(nb_frames)
    ffm_filename = filename

    if platform.system() == 'Linux':
        ffm_path = 'ffmpeg'
        ffm_format = '-f v4l2'

    else:
        ffm_path = 'C:/Program Files/iSpy/ffmpeg.exe'
        ffm_format = '-f image2'

    command = [ffm_path, ffm_input, ffm_rate, ffm_format, ffm_nb_frames, ffm_filename]
    subprocess.call(command)

    print(command)
```

BTW, I'm running this command on a MT7688.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to split the options:

```
command = [ffm_path, '-i', ffm_input, '-r', ffm_rate, '-f', ffm_format, '-vframes',  ffm_nb_frames, ffm_filename]
```

The `ffm_input`, `ffm_rate`, `ffm_format` should only contain the value:

```
ffm_input = self.path
ffm_rate = '5'
ffm_nd_frames = str(nb_frames)
ffm_format = 'v412' if platform.system() == 'Linux' else 'image2'
```

When you pass a list no parsing is done so `-r 5` is taken as a single argument but the program expects you to provide two separate arguments `-r` followed by `5`.

---

Basically if you put them as a single element in the list it's as if you quoted them on the command line:

```
$ echo "-n hello"
-n hello
$ echo -n hello
hello$
```

In the first example `echo` sees a single argument `-n hello`. Since it does not match any option it just prints it. In the second case `echo` sees two arguments `-n` and `hello`, the first is the valid option to suppress end of line and as you can see the prompt is printed right after `hello` and not on its own line.

Comment: this is a life saver! i know we shouldn't comment if we are grateful, but this has not been indicated in the documentation of `subprocess`